# Kubernetes Service LoadBalancer "EXTERNAL-IP" remains "<none>" instead of taking worker nodes public IP addresses

Tags: kubernetes, vpn, kubernetes-networking

I have 5 VPS with a public network interface for each, for which I have configured a VPN.

- 3 nodes are Kubernetes masters where I have set the Kubelet `--node-ip` flag as their private IP address.
- One of the 3 nodes have a HAProxy load balancer for the Kubernetes masters, listening on the private IP, so that all the nodes used the private IP address of the load balancer in order to join the cluster.
- 2 nodes are Kubernetes workers where I didn't set the Kubelet `--node-ip` flag so that their node IP is the public address.

The cluster is healthy and I have deploy my application and its dependencies.

Now I'd like to access the app from the Internet, so I've deployed a edge router and created a Kubernetes Service with the type `LoadBalancer`.

The service is well created but never takes the worker nodes' public IP addresses as `EXTERNAL-IP`.

Assigning the IP addresses manually works, but obviously want that to be automatic.

I have read about [the MetalLb project](http://metallb.universe.tf), but it doesn't seem to fit in my case as it is supposed to have a range of IP addresses to distribute, while here I have one public IP address per node, and not in the same range.

So who can I configure Kubernetes so that my Service of type LoadBalancer gets automatically the public IP addresses as `EXTERNAL-IP`?

Answer (score 0):

I finally can answer myself in two times.

### Without an external Load Balancer

Firstly, in order to solve the problem from my question, the only way I found which worked quite well was to set the `externalIPs` of my `LoadBalancer` service with the IP addresses of the Kubernetes worker nodes.

Those nodes were running Traefik and therefor had it listening on ports 80 and 443.

After that, I've created as many A DNS entries as I have Kubernetes worker nodes, pointing each to the Kubernetes respective worker node public IP address. This setup makes the DNS server returning the list of IP addresses, in a random order, and then the web browser will take care of trying the first IP address, then the second one if the first is down and so on.

The downside of this, is when you want to drain a node for maintenance, or when it crashes, the web browser will wast time trying to reach it until it tries the next IP address.

So here come the second option: External Load balancer.

### With an external Load Balancer

I took another VPS where I've installed HAproxy and configured a SSL passthrough of the Kubernetes API port so that it load balancer the trafic to the master nodes, without terminating it.

With this solution, I removed the `externalIPs` field from my `Service` and I've installed MetalLB with a single IP address configured with this manifest:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: staging-public-ips
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 1.2.3.4/32
```

When the `LoadBalancer` `Service` is created, MetalLB assigns this IP address and calls the Kubernetes APIs accordingly.

This has solved [my issue to integrate my Kubernetes cluster with Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/324062).

**WARNING:** MetalLB will assign **only once** the IP address so that if you have a second `LoadBalancer` `Service`, it will remain in `Pending` state forever, until you give a new IP address to MetalLB.